# Setting up Schunk LWA3 on indigo, cannot initialize the robot

Tags: ros, schunk

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was wondering what is the proper way to set up Schunk LWA3 arm (older, gold colored modules)?

I'm currently using the code in the schunk_robots library (with the necessary dependencies installed), and I am unable to initialize my arm. So I guess I have a several questions:

Would the same code as what is in schunk_modular_robotics and schunk_robots for the LWA4d work for an LWA3?

I'm using a Peak usb-can adapter, and right now I'm using it with the default drivers as recommended (http://wiki.ros.org/socketcan_interface), but because this is an older version of the arm, is this the right thing to do? Or should I compile the pcan driver (with chardev?)?

I'm also wondering if I should be using the schunk_powercube_chain instead, but there is no documentation or code samples for it for indigo, and the last version which calls it is schunk_bringup in groovy . . .

Thank you for your help, I'm a little new at working with real hardware.

-------  details -------

(please let me know if there is any other information I should provide)

I have an older LWA, with only 6 joints (I've modified the relevant files, correctly, I think)

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, using ROS Indigo

I'm using the pcan-usb adapter, with the following initialization:

```
    sudo ip link set can0 up type can bitrate 500000
```

the following drivers are loaded:

```
    lsmod | grep can

      can_raw                17120  0 

      can                    36575  1 can_raw

      can_dev                20764  1 peak_usb
```

---

when I try to run robot.launch I get the following:

```
    core service [/rosout] found
    process[arm/robot_state_publisher-1]: started with pid [3921]
    process[arm/driver-2]: started with pid [3922]
    process[arm/joint_state_controller_spawner-3]: started with pid [3923]
    process[arm/cob_control_mode_adapter_node-4]: started with pid [3924]
    [ INFO] [1427125862.856646100]: waitForService: Service [/arm/controller_manager/load_controller] has not been advertised, waiting...
    process[arm/joint_states_relay-5]: started with pid [3992]
    [ INFO] [1427125867.860408810]: waitForService: Service [/arm/controller_manager/load_controller] has not been advertised, waiting...
```

when I attempt to initialize the robot (I tried different node ids for the first module (3/4/5/6))

```
    rosservice call /arm/driver/init

    success: 
      data: False
    error_message: 
      data: could not reset node '3'
```

other terminal window:

```
    [ INFO] [1427128285.876938150]: Initializing XXX
    [ INFO] [1427128285.877114246]: Current state: 1 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
    [ INFO] [1427128285.877209232]: Current state: 2 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
    [ INFO] [1427128286.816488654]: waitForService: Service [/arm/controller_manager/load_controller] has not been advertised, waiting...
    [ INFO] [1427128291.820936133]: waitForService: Service [/arm/controller_manager/load_controller] has not been advertised, waiting...
    SHUTDOWN
    [ INFO] [1427128295.978245127]: Current state: 2 device error: system:125 internal_error: 0 (OK)
    [ INFO] [1427128295.978322473]: Current state: 2 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
    [ INFO] [1427128295.978352019]: Current state: 0 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
    [ INFO] [1427128295.978370652]: Current state: 0 device error: system:0 internal_error: 0 (OK)
    SHUTDOWN
    [ INFO] [1427128296.823728257]: waitForService: Service [/arm/controller_manager/load_controller] has not been advertised, waiting...
    [ INFO] [1427128301.827175893]: waitForService: Service [/arm/controller_manager/load_controller] has not been advertised, waiting...
```

I checked what the can driver is doing (after googling for a while), and this is what I have:

```
    cat /proc/net/can/stats

    7 transmitted frames (TXF)
    7 received frames (RXF)
    7 matched frames (RXMF)

  100 % total match ratio (RXMR)
    0 frames/s total tx rate (TXR)
    0 frames/s total rx rate (RXR)

  100 % current match ratio (CRXMR)
    0 frames/s current tx rate (CTXR)
    0 frames/s current rx rate (CRXR)

  100 % max match ratio (MRXMR)
    6 frames/s max tx rate (MTXR)
    6 frames/s max rx rate (MRXR)

    0 current receive list entries (CRCV)
    2 maximum receive list entries (MRCV)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205693/setting-up-schunk-lwa3-on-indigo,-cannot-initialize-the-robot./) by [EvilPictureBook](https://answers.ros.org/users/21954/evilpicturebook/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2015-03-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PatFGarrett](https://answers.ros.org/users/34824/patfgarrett/) on 2018-04-25**:
Hello, where you ever able to get this working?

**Comment by [EvilPictureBook](https://answers.ros.org/users/21954/evilpicturebook/) on 2018-05-02**:
Yes, I was. It was quite a while ago, so I would need to look over the code and my notes, but if you have questions about getting the older Schunks running I'll do my best to answer.

**Comment by [PatFGarrett](https://answers.ros.org/users/34824/patfgarrett/) on 2018-05-04**:
Thank you so much for the response. The main issue I have is initializing the arms and what the order of operations (commands) needs to be to launch the proper nodes. The powercube node crashes saying that ros params are not set ( Im pretty sure im setting them properly). Any help is awesome!

**Comment by [EvilPictureBook](https://answers.ros.org/users/21954/evilpicturebook/) on 2018-05-04**:
Sure, I'm back at that lab next week, so I can take a look. But for now, if you cab post how you're launching it (launch files, any yaml param files etc) I'll be able to compare.

Also, are you using a specific CAN adapter, or have dedicated can hardware?

**Comment by [PatFGarrett](https://answers.ros.org/users/34824/patfgarrett/) on 2018-05-08**:
Hello, im back in the lab now. The current set up is Schunk LWA3, PCAN PCIe card (ive tried with and without the drivers, also as net and char devices), ROS Kinetic.
The process that I have been trying is powering on the arm, roscore, rosrun canopen driver, rosrun powercube

**Comment by [PatFGarrett](https://answers.ros.org/users/34824/patfgarrett/) on 2018-05-12**:
Hello, so I have made a lot of changes. Essentially I have shcunk_bringup launching powercube and the joint stuff, then I use rosservice call /arm_controller/init. the Pcan device initializes fine but then I get a -207 error when it tries to write to module. I think its  an error with the module IDs

**Comment by [EvilPictureBook](https://answers.ros.org/users/21954/evilpicturebook/) on 2018-05-14**:
Sorry for the large delay between replies. So, I haven't ran the robot since indigo, so all the code is as it was then.

I ran it with the char device (using pcan drivers)

launching with  https://gist.github.com/EvilPictureBook/028bfeb7cac9871bad99584280bb7ed2

**Comment by [EvilPictureBook](https://answers.ros.org/users/21954/evilpicturebook/) on 2018-05-14**:
I also remember having to make changes to some parts of libm5api. I made a repo for that code (look through the commits, there are only a few), keep in mind this was a long time ago, so . . . the code is a bit of a mess: https://github.com/EvilPictureBook/lwa_hacks

let me know if any of this helps.

**Comment by [EvilPictureBook](https://answers.ros.org/users/21954/evilpicturebook/) on 2018-05-14**:
One more thing, it may be helpful to spoof some of the CAN messages to see if the correct ones are being sent, and if the joints are responding appropriately. You can even craft some manually to ask for ID or serial number, to see if the arm behaves well.

**Comment by [PatFGarrett](https://answers.ros.org/users/34824/patfgarrett/) on 2018-05-14**:
Thank you! I will try all this today and let you know

**Comment by [PatFGarrett](https://answers.ros.org/users/34824/patfgarrett/) on 2018-05-14**:
Hello, I have everything compiling in indigo on 14.04. I cannot use your launch file as I do not have the .yaml's you indicated in your launch file or the .xacro. Could you share?

**Comment by [EvilPictureBook](https://answers.ros.org/users/21954/evilpicturebook/) on 2018-05-14**:
I added the `lwa_lab_robot` folder to the repo.

You can look at what's in there and use that to writ your con figs; but you would need your own configurations for your arm.

**Comment by [PatFGarrett](https://answers.ros.org/users/34824/patfgarrett/) on 2018-05-14**:
So I made the config changes I think are needed and when I launch and then call /init i get

```
[PROT-DEV] readUnsignedShort
[PROT] call readDevice() . . . '''

Ill look deeper into the code but any idea? Im using pcan as char and used cat /proc/pcan to find the device
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi dignakov,

the good package to start would be *schunk_lwa4d* but you should consider that this package will user *ros_canopen* (CANOpen protocol) to communicate with the arm. If your arm/modules uses M5-Protocol than you should use shunk_powercube_chain (one updated version is [here](https://github.com/iirob/schunk_modular_robotics)). If your arm is using SM-Protocol than probably you should implement communication to it by yourself (I don't know any package providing this).

Hope it helps a bit (even though I am probably to late),

Denis

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2016-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0